# How to determine that UIViewController was started for the first time?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewControllers hierarchy, with UINavigationViewController as the root.
How can I find out whether some ViewController was started for the first time or it was started as a result of unwinding of the navigation stack?

Comment: Are you talking about doing a check in the `viewWillAppear` function to know whether it is appearing because it's the first time the view appeared or because some other view was dismissed?

Comment: @rmaddy doing a check in the viewWillAppear function to know if this is the first time view will appear

Comment: What's your use case? I would generally recommend that you manage your state outside of your view controller and simple update it in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assuming you wish to know if `viewWillAppear:` (or `viewDidAppear:`) is being called when the view controller is first being displayed or if it's being displayed because another view controller has been dismissed, you can easily do the following:

Newer Swift versions:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if isBeingPresented || isMovingToParent {
        // This is the first time this instance of the view controller will appear
    } else {
        // This controller is appearing because another was just dismissed
    }
}
```

Older Swift versions:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if isBeingPresented() || isMovingToParentViewController() {
        // This is the first time this instance of the view controller will appear
    } else {
        // This controller is appearing because another was just dismissed
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me for any view controllers inside of a UITabBarController ‍♂️

Comment: This should be reversed

Answer (score 0):

when you push new viewcontroller on your navigation stack, it is instantiate first time, and when you pop it out from stack it is dealloc or released. so when you push or go forward then it is first time but when you come back to any viewcontroller from previous then current vc is already in memory and not first time!!!

Comment: if init method is called this means that VC is started for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

On Objective-C it looks like:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if ([self isBeingPresented] || [self isMovingToParentViewController]) {
        // This is the first time
    } else {
        // This is the NOT first time
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/first-posts/26249142)

Answer (score 0):

isBeingPresented and isMovingToParent are tricky one.

My method is to create a counter and increment it in viewWillAppear.

```
var viewWillAppearCounter = 0

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if viewWillAppearCounter == 0 {
        print("viewWillAppear will be executed for the first time")
    } else {
        print("viewWillAppear was already executed \(viewWillAppearCounter) times")
    }
    viewWillAppearCounter += 1
}
```